# Single Sidebar; multiple templates! How?

Tags: posts, pages, templates, sidebar

I am calling the typical `get_sidebar()` method to produce a vertical sidebar on posts/pages. Because of the responsive and multiple format nature of our site, the designer decided to make full-width content posts/pages with no sidebar, but using the same sidebar content below the content, in a horizontal fashion (utilizing bootstrap's grid). Is it possible to use one sidebar instance, and conditionally output multiple formats from the elements of the sidebar?

Comment: Could this not be solved using just CSS?

Comment: Short answer: no

Comment: Also note that `get_sidebar` is just a thin wrapper around `get_template_part`, look inside the `sidebar.php` of your theme for the actual code that loads the widgets

Comment: Ok will do. Thanks. If I can set conditions on the page format type, and if `get_template_part()` is viable that would totally work.

Comment: Specifically look for the calls to `dynamic_sidebar`. Eitherway I still think the fundamental issue is you're relying on HTML classes to define grids/columns, rather than using CSS to assign them from the stylesheets. SCSS/LESS would make this trivial, all you'd have to do is wrap it in a div with a class you could use to flip between the two formats. Else you're probably going to need to create a whole new sidebar and duplicate all the widgets so that you can change their before and after markup

Comment: Unfortunately my project lead wants to stick to a bootstrap standard, for the sake of standards and consistency in the codebase. I agree with you, but unfortunately a vertical sidebar's HTML structure does not cater to bootstrap's grid. I will look more into your suggestion though.